# How to format decimals in Clustered column chart in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

This is the problem I am facing, Picture depicts it much clear :

[image]

I want to set the precision point of average temperature to **25.30**.
I have tried all the properties of data labels also.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose your field first on Fields Pane, and then in the modeling tab, you can choose how many decimal places you wanna show:

[image]

In your case, you might create a measure called Average of Temperature (rather than using Average aggregation) and change this measure decimal place to 2.